# vehicle will only pull when in 4 low. its a5 speed. at first it just happened to reverse but now it's the forward gears too

Tags: chevrolet, acceleration, 4wd, blazer, s10

My 4x4 5 speed s10 blazer will only go when it's in 4 low. When it first happened it was only reverse but now it's the forward gears too

Comment: You need to describe the situation a bit more. Do you mean that you can't find a gear? Or it has not enough power to go higher gear?